# How do I load the same script multiple times?

Tags: vimscript

I would like to have a line in a vimscript that would load this exact script once again. What I tried to do is to:

- firstly set the guards, like `if !exists("g:second_load")` (and it
  worked),
- and secondly, inside this guard, to load the same plugin with `source` and `runtime`, with `%` (gives the name of the file being opened
  by Vim) and `<sfile>` (just doesn't work).

What I am trying to achieve is something like that:

```
 " --- here comes the rest of the file with all the commands, etc ---

 if !exists("g:file_second_source")
     let g:file_second_source = 1
     " source this plugin once again
 endif
```

Comment: Perhaps `execute 'source' expand('<sfile>')`?

Comment: Simply `source <sfile>` is enough.

Comment: Both options seem to work, thank you! Must have done something wrong from the outset. Anyways, would expand the question with both of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is answered in comments.

D. Ben Knoble suggested to do `execute 'source' expand('<sfile>')`.

Matt suggested just `source <sfile>`.

Both options seem to work properly.